# How to bind form Code activity to XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, android-activity, workflow-activity

I'm trying to make an activity designer library. I have two sources; one of them is `CodeActivity` in C# code and the other one is Activity designer in XAML. In `CodeActivity`, I have a public property `Name`. In XAML, I want to view and change it's value through binding. [My XAML design is like this](http://1.cpro.netai.net/images/0b5f25a22857.png)

I declared `Name` property like this:

```
private string _name;
public string Name { 
    get { return _name; } 
    set 
    { 
        _name = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
    } 
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And my XAML is like this:

```
...    
<DataTemplate x:Key="Expanded">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name :" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
        <sap:WorkflowItemPresenter Item="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Body, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            HintText="Please drop an activity here" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've tried a lot of ways, but I couldn't do it.
How can I show the `Name` property from `CodeActivity` in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
When we want to bind a variable from CodeActivity Side to XAML, we do like this :

```
...
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" /> 
...
<sapv:ExpressionTextBox HintText="Enter custom text here ..." Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=In}" ExpressionType="s:String" OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" MaxLines="1"/>
...
```